# Reviendrez or reviendriez?

Tags: grammaire, littérature

About the poem *Ce qu'il y a dans l'oeil du chat* of Marc Alyn, I saw two versions

Verion 1 from the site [De la lecture pour les enfants et de la lecture pour les parents](https://lectureenfantparent.wordpress.com/2020/06/13/poesie-ce-quil-y-a-dans-loeil-du-chat-marc-alyn/):

> Si vous saviez ce qu’il y a
> Dans l’oeil sans fond d’un petit chat,
> Qu’il soit jaune, vert ou lilas
> Vrai, vous n’en reviendriez pas!
>
> On y voit des oiseaux de lune,
> Des palais de laine et de lait,
> Le Sphinx émergeant de ses dunes,
> Et des ballets ultraviolets.
>
> Sur des bassins d’une eau sans rides
> S’épanouit la fleur de lotus
> Tandis qu’une main transluscide
> Peint des soleils sur papyrus.
>
> Tout l’univers est reflété
> Dans cette goutte de lumière
> Qui ouvre sur l’éternité
> Ainsi qu’un hublot sur la mer.

Vers 2 from [Poèmes](https://www.poemes.co/ce-qu-il-y-a-dans-l-oeil-du-chat.html), with everything almost the same except instead of *reviendriez*, it uses *reviendez*:

> Qu’il soit jaune, vert ou lilas Vrai,
> vous n’en reviendrez pas!

May I ask, which version is better?

Comment: A typo: the line break is between *lait* and *Le*, and not after *Le*.

Comment: @PeterShor sorry about that, just corrected.

Comment: This is an irrelevant aside, but when I first read the poem I thought it was saying that the cat was yellow, green, or lilac. But now I realize that it's the cat's eye.

Comment: @PeterShor i think it's a poem for children, maybe nonsense is ok :)

Comment: There's another discrepancy between the two versions. In the first, it's *Le Sphinx émergeant de ses dunes*, which makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @PeterShor you’re definitely right. I’ve rectified it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *reviendriez*.

There are two ways of seeing this. First, getting rid of the intervening clauses, the first verse is a sentence that reads:

> Si vous saviez ... vous n’en reviendriez pas!

And according to [the grammar of *si* clauses](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/grammar/si-clauses-conditionals/), if the verb after *si* is in the imperfect, the main verb should  be in the conditional.

Second, this poem is an *octasyllabe*, which means there are 8 syllables in each line. The only way to get 8 syllables is to syllabify it as:

> Vrai, vous n’en re·vien·dri·ez pas!

If the word were *reviendrez*, the line would only have seven syllables

Comment: I did found each line is about 7 or 8 syllables.. just curious : for "Si vous saviez ce qu’il y a"  to have 8, seems "qu'il y a" need to be 4? but normally I read it as "qui·l y·a", seems there're only 3?

Comment: You are right that *qu'il y a* only has three syllables, but the rest of the line has five. *Si · vous · sa·viez · ce · qu’il · y · a*. And you do need to make some pronunciation decisions to get eight syllables in each line,  but aside from the treatment of mute e, which is handled the way it usually is in French poetry, they're all reasonably consistent with normal French pronunciation.

Comment: Sorry I miscounted the first line. On the mute e, is it the 3rd line? i.e. Qu’il soit jaune, vert ou lilas  = Qu’il ·  soit  · jau · ne, ·  vert ·  ou ·  li · las = 8?

Comment: The syllable count reasoning doesn't work: *reviendrez* could be pronounced *re-vi-en-drez*. The word *reviendriez* could be pronounced any of *re-vien-driez* (3), *re-vi-en-driez* (4), *re-vien-dri-ez* (4) or *re-vi-en-dri-ez* (5). I do find /dʁje/ hard to pronounce so *re-vien-dri-ez* is what I would consider the “normal” pronunciation, but *re-vi-en-dri-ez* would be unremarkable if the meter required it.

Comment: thank you both, now i learnt a lot!